# A General Version of the Conditional Relative Entropy

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, entropy, radon-nikodym

In general, the relative entropy is defined for all probability measures $\mu,\nu$ with $\mu\ll\nu$ (absolutely continuous), and given as $D(\mu\|\nu)=\int f\mathrm d\nu$, where $f(x)=\Lambda(\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial\nu}(x))$ and $\Lambda(x)=x\ln(x)$.
Also, it's reasonable to set $D(\mu\|\nu)=\infty$ otherwise.
Notice that we may equivalently understand $D(\mu\|\nu)=D(\nu,\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial\nu})$ as a function of a measure and a derivative for that measure, i.e. $D(\nu,f)$ is defined whenever $\int f\mathrm d\nu=1$.

For the question, I'd rather move to random variables, so let $(X,Y)\in\mathcal X\times\mathcal Y$. If we have $\mathbb E[R(X)]=1$ for some $R:\mathcal X\rightarrow\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, the relative entropy $D(X,R)=D(\nu,R)$ is the relative entropy with respect to the distribution $\nu$ of $X$.

**QUESTION**: Suppose we have $\mathbb E[R(X,Y)]=1$, $R\ge 0$, wouldn't it make sense to define the conditional relative entropy as
$$D_{\mathrm{c}}((X,Y),R)=\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E[R(X,Y)|X]\Lambda\left(\frac{R(X,Y)}{\mathbb E[R(X,Y)|X]}\right)\right],$$
using $\frac{0}{0}=0$?

**MOTIVATION**: Here's why I think that this make sense.

1. This definition is general, it matches $D((X,Y),R)=\mathbb E[\Lambda(R(X,Y))]$.
2. It's non-negative, since with the tower property and Jensen's inequality we have
   $$\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E[R(X,Y)|X]\mathbb E\left[\Lambda\left(\frac{R(X,Y)}{\mathbb E[R(X,Y)|X]}\right)\middle|X\right]\right]\ge 0.$$
3. With the factorization lemma we get $R_X:\mathcal X\rightarrow\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ with $\mathbb E[R(X,Y)|X]=R_X\circ X$, and $\mathbb E[R_X(X)]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[R(X,Y)|X]]=1$, the Radon-Nikodm derivative for the first coordinate, which gives
   $$D_{\mathrm{c}}((X,Y),R)=\mathbb E\left[R(X,Y)\ln\left(\frac{R(X,Y)}{R_X(X)}\right)\right]
   =D((X,Y),R)-D(X,R_X)$$
   using the tower property for the second part, meaning that the chain rule holds.
4. Since the chain rule holds, this is always the correct definition. There's a closely related problem with [conditional Radon-Nikodym derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340456/existence-of-conditional-density-given-conditional-distribution). If the conditional derivative exists, it is equal to $R(x,y)/R_X(x)$ (as for regular conditional distributions). So, if we work on Borel spaces (or equivalently countably generated), these definitions coincide with the [kernel based definitions](https://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/data/LN_fdiv.pdf).
5. It clearly directly generalizes to $f$-divergences. Since these are usually treated in a very general manner in the first place, I think it would be a fit, however it doesn't seem to be in use (says Google). Also, since this definition does not rely on kernels, it does not rely on the theory and thus prevents [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804682/conditional-radon-nikodym-and-disintegration) like this one.

Since the actual question is, well, not of a mathematical nature, I'll add this question.
Can we establish the other basic properties of conditional $f$-divergences? In particular, I was not able to show convexity without additional assumptions. This means, writing $D_{\mathrm{c}}(\mu,\nu)=D_{\mathrm{c}}((X,Y),R)$, where $\mu$ is the distribution of $(X,Y)$ and $\nu$ is given by the Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to $\mu$, can we show that $D_{\mathrm{c}}(\mu,\nu)$ is jointly convex in its arguments?